# How do I compute this limit: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1-\frac1{x^2}\right)^{x^2-1} = \frac1e$?

Tags: limits, exponential-function

So as part of a problem, I need to compute the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1-\frac1{x^2}\right)^{x^2-1} = \frac1e$$

As can be seen, the answer is $\frac1e$. But how do I get there? I entered the limit on Wolfram Alpha, and obtained the answer. But the step-by-step solution was not available. How has this been obtained? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac1{x^2}\right)^{x^2-1}=\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[1+\left(-\dfrac1{x^2}\right)\right]^{-x^2}\right)^{\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}}$$

Now use $\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1u\right)^u=e$

Comment: $$\left(1-\dfrac1{x^2}\right)^{x^2-1} = \frac 1 {\left(1-\dfrac1{x^2}\right)^{-x^2}\left(1-\dfrac1{x^2}\right)}$$

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp, Could not make out

Comment: What does "to make out" mean?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp, Could not understand

Comment: You cannot understand what I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

An identity for $\frac{1}{e}$ is:

$\frac{1}{e} = \lim_{x \to \infty}(1-\frac{1}{x})^x$

If you know that I think it makes sense to try this first because it looks so similar:

$\lim_{x \to \infty}(1 - \frac{1}{x^2})^{x^2-1}$

$= \lim_{x \to \infty}((1 - \frac{1}{x^2})^{x^2} \cdot (1 - \frac{1}{x^2})^{-1})$

$= \lim_{x \to \infty}(1 - \frac{1}{x^2})^{x^2} \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty}(1 - \frac{1}{x^2})^{-1}$ (justified because both limits exist)

$= \lim_{x \to \infty}(1 - \frac{1}{x^2})^{x^2} \cdot 1$

$= \lim_{x \to \infty}(1 - \frac{1}{x^2})^{x^2}$

$= \lim_{x \to \infty}(1 - \frac{1}{x})^{x}$ (justified because $x^2$ is increasing and unbounded)

$= \frac{1}{e}$

Answer (score 0):

Take the natural log first, then evaluate the limit from there:
$$\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{x^2-1}=(x^2-1)\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
As $x\to\infty$, $x^2-1\to\infty$ and $\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\to\ln(1)=0$, so their product is an indeterminate form. If we can get this into a ratio of infinity to infinity or zero to zero, we can use L'Hopital's rule. Let's try moving the $x^2-1$ into the denominator:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{1/(x^2-1)}$$
Now as $x\to\infty$ we get the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$, so we can use L'Hospital's. Take the derivative of the top and bottom.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{x^3}}{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)/\left(\frac{-2x}{(x^2-1)^2}\right)$$
Rearranging this we get 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}-\left(\frac{\frac{2}{x}}{x^2-1}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{(x^2-1)^2}{2x}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}-\frac{1}{x^2}(x^2-1)=-1$$
Now we raise $e$ to the power of this (to undo the log from the beginning), and we get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{x^2-1}=e^{-1}=\frac{1}{e}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can write the limit as

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left((1-\frac{1}{x^2})^{1-x^2}\right)^{-1}=\left((\lim_{x \to \infty}(1-\frac{1}{x^2})^{-x^2}\cdot(1-\frac{1}{x^2})\right)^{-1}=(e\cdot1)^{-1}=\frac{1}{e}$$

Here $\lim_{y\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{y})^y=e$

Answer (score 0):

*This solution does not require L'Hopital. However, it does require the following daunting identity. [To learn more about it (trust me, once you've used it once, you'll never want to forget it), see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147693/regarding-e-in-lim-limits-x-to-a-phix-psix-e-lim-limits-x).*

> $$\lim\limits_{x \to a}{\phi(x)^{\psi(x)}} = e^{\lim\limits_{x \to a}{[(\phi(x)-1)\psi(x)}]}$$

Using this identity...

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}{(1-\frac{1}{x^2})^{x^2-1}}$
$= e^{\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}{[((1-\frac{1}{x^2}) - 1)(x^2-1)]}} = e^\theta$

$\theta$
$= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}{[((1-\frac{1}{x^2}) - 1)(x^2-1)]}$
$= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}{-\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}} = -1$

$e^\theta = e^{-1} = \frac{1}{e}$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}{(1-\frac{1}{x^2})^{x^2-1}} = \frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: Wow, where can I find the derivation of that identity?

Comment: @Einsteinthetroll -- See the link in the answer. It was a lot of work to derive it, but very satisfying once I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$A=\left(1-\dfrac1{x^2}\right)^{x^2-1}$$ Take logarithms $$\log(A)=(x^2-1)\log\left(1-\dfrac1{x^2}\right)$$ Consider that for small $t$ Taylor series is $$\log(1-t)=-t-\frac{t^2}{2}+O\left(t^3\right)$$ Replace $t$ by $\dfrac1{x^2}$ which makes $$\log\left(1-\dfrac1{x^2}\right)=-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$ 
$$\log(A)=(x^2-1)\log\left(1-\dfrac1{x^2}\right)=(x^2-1)\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right) \right)$$ $$\log(A)=-1+\frac{1}{2 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$ Now, Taylor again $$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{2 e x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$ which shows not only the limit but also how it is approached.