# How to find $\lim_{x\to1}\left(\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)^{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

> Find
>   $$\lim_{x\to1}\left(\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)^{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}}$$

---

**My attempt:** ON THE basis of [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147693/regarding-e-in-lim-limits-x-to-a-phix-psix-e-lim-limits-x)
$$\lim_{x\to1}\tan\frac{\pi x}{4} =1,\quad \lim_{x\to1}\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}=\infty$$

$$\implies\lim_{x\to1}\left(\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)^{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}}= e^{\lim_{x\to1}\left[\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}-1\right]\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}}$$

Now I need to solve $\lim_{x\to1}\left[\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}-1\right]\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}$, but I don't know how to go on.

Comment: Could you explain why $$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)^{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}} = e^{\lim_{x\to 1}\left[\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}-1\right]\tan \frac{\pi x}{2}}$$?  I don't understand that.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang That is a standard result for functions like {f(x)}^g(x)

Comment: Maybe so.  But where does it come from?

Comment: Go ahead and precede commons three-letter functions with a \ so they appear upright, like `\lim` $\lim$ and `\tan` $\tan$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The standard result is for lim$_{x\longrightarrow a}$$\left\{ f(x)\right\} $$^{g(x)}$if
lim$_{x\longrightarrow a}$\{f(x)\}=1 and lim$_{x\longrightarrow a}$g(x)=
$\infty$$\Longrightarrow$ lim$_{x\longrightarrow a}$$\left\{ f(x)\right\} $$^{g(x)}$
=e$^{lim_{x\longrightarrow a}\{f(x)-1\}g(x)}$ . please do not downvote my question. tell me what is wrong first.

Comment: I keep asking you to explain it, but you're just repeating it.  Do you know **why** it's true?  My point is that this might not be the most appropriate formula for the problem.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang ok , so the truth is I do not know. I am preparing for a competition . i don't have enough time to think about the logics behind the formulas. i am only worried about solving as many question as possible.i hope you understand it.Proof of the result is not given in my book

Comment: Aside from the fact that you phrased your question in the imperative mood ("Please solve it."), which is considered rude in this community, your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @MatthewLeingang In my community it is said that Rod is god .You have the rod .No more explanations

Comment: @MatthewLeingang This is not XY problem.I asked help for solving $\lim_{x\to1}\left[\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}-1\right]\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}$
Ok now see

$\lim_{x\to1}\left[\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}-1\right]\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}$=
$\lim_{x\to1}\left[\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}-1\right]\frac{2tan\frac{\Pi x}{4}}{(1+tan\frac{\Pi x}{4})(1-tan\frac{\Pi x}{4})}=lim_{x\longrightarrow1}\frac{-2tan\frac{\Pi x}{4}}{1+tan\frac{\Pi x}{4}}$$\Longrightarrow$$\frac{-2}{2}$=
-1$\Longrightarrow$Answer is $\frac{1}{e}$. So i was right in my question. I used, please because I need the answer

Comment: Since i have cleared everything will everyone be enough kind  to take their downvotes back

Comment: Re: *Proof of the result is not given in my book.* Probably you could improve the question by explicitly saying the source instead of just saying *my book*. And you could also clearly state the result you are using in your attempt also in the post, not just in comments.

Comment: Perhaps you could also quote this post in connection with that result: [Regarding $e$ in $\lim\limits_{x \to a}{[\phi(x)]^{\psi(x)}} = e^{\lim\limits_{x \to a}{[\phi(x) - 1]\psi(x)}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2147693).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\left(\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)^{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\left(1+\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}-1}\cdot\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}\left(\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}-1\right)}=$$
$$=e^{-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow}\frac{2\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}}{1+\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}}}=e^{-1}=\frac{1}{e}.$$
I used $\tan2\alpha=\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1-\tan^2\alpha}=-\frac{2\tan\alpha}{(\tan\alpha-1)(1+\tan\alpha)}.$

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\left(\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)^{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}} = \lim_{x \to 1}e^ {{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}}\ln(\tan\frac{\pi x}{4})}$$
Now we will check 
\begin{align*}
     \lim_{x \to 1} {{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}}\ln\left(\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)} 
    &\stackrel{\text{(L'Hôpital's rule)}}{=}
    \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{-\frac{\pi}{4}\tan^2(\frac{x\pi}{2})\cos^2(\frac{x\pi}{2})}{\cos^2(\frac{x\pi}{4})\tan(\frac{x\pi}{4})} \\&= \frac{\frac{-1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} = -1
\
\end{align*}

and therefore:
$\lim_{x \to 1} e^{{{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}}\ln(\tan\frac{\pi x}{4})}} = e^{-1}$

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for.  Good work. (PS: I reformatted, hope that's OK)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\tan\dfrac\pi4+1=u$ and using $\tan2A=\dfrac{2\tan A}{1-\tan^2A}$

$$\lim_{x\to1}\left(\tan\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)^{\tan\frac{\pi x}{2}}$$

$$=\lim_{u\to0}(1+u)^{\frac{2(u-1)}{1-(u-1)^2}}$$

$$=\left(\lim_{u\to0}(1+u)^{1/u}\right)^{\lim_{u\to0}\frac{2u(u-1)}{2u-u^2}}$$

Clearly, $\lim_{u\to0}(1+u)^{1/u}=e$ and 
$$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{2u(u-1)}{2u-u^2}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{2(u-1)}{2-u}=?$$

Answer (score 2):

Using your formula you have already covered the hard part. To proceed further just put $t=\tan (\pi x/4)$ so that $\tan(\pi x/2)=2t/(1-t^{2})$. The limit at the end of your question is $$\lim_{t\to 1}(t-1)\cdot\dfrac{2t}{1-t^{2}}=\lim_{t\to 1}-\frac{2t}{1+t}=-1$$ and the desired answer is $e^{-1}=1/e$.

---

By the way "not thinking about logics..." and "solving as many problems..." is not the way to beat competition because almost everyone is trying these easy approaches. You should go for "understanding basics" and this is the ability which separates the wheat from chaff in such competitions.