# Computing: $ \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}} (\tan{x})^{\tan{2x}} $ without L'Hopital - tan and exponential

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

I've encountered the following limit:

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}} (\tan{x})^{\tan{2x}} $$

How to find this limit?

I tried the following formula:

$$ \tan{x} = \frac{\tan{2x}-\tan{x}}{1+\tan{2x}\tan{2}}$$

But I still haven't figure it out yet. Still I hope it is helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate The limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469040/evaluate-the-limit)

Comment: @kingW3 I think it's a similar problem, but it's really not duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Well with the substitution $\pi x/4=t$ it becomes the same.

Comment: @kingW3 By your reasoning all problems in Math are the same.

Comment: @kingW3 Thanks for the comment anyway, I'll jump to that question and have a look

Comment: @R.Feng No problem, if you think the link doesn't answer your question I'll retract my vote.

Answer (score 2):

To make life easier, let $x=y+\frac \pi 4$ which makes 
$$A=\left(\tan{(x)}\right)^{\tan{(2x)}}=\left(\tan \left(y+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\right)^{-\cot (2 y)}$$ Take logarithms
$$\log(A)={-\cot (2 y)}\log \left(\tan \left(y+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\right)$$ Now, using Taylor expansions around $y=0$
$$\tan \left(y+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)=1+2 y+2 y^2+\frac{8 y^3}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)$$
$$\log \left(\tan \left(y+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\right)=2 y+\frac{4 y^3}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ 
$$\cot (2 y)=\frac{1}{2 y}-\frac{2 y}{3}-\frac{8 y^3}{45}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ All of that makes 
$$\log(A)=-1+\frac{2 y^2}{3}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ Now, Taylor again
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{1}{e}+\frac{2 y^2}{3 e}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ which shows not only the limit but also how it is approached.

**Edit**

Since we know the exact values of trigonometric functions for multiples of $\frac \pi {24}$ (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi24.html) and  [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi12.html)) let us make the computations for $y=\pm \frac \pi {24}$. The "exact" value is $\approx 0.372170$ while the small expansion leads to $\approx 0.372082$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}} (\tan{x})^{\tan{2x}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}} (1+\tan{x}-1)^{\frac{1}{\tan{x}-1}\cdot(\tan{x}-1)\tan{2x}}=$$
$$=e^{- \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{2\tan{x}}{1+\tan{x}}}=\frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: not sure how this helps

Comment: @windircurse  If you not sure why do you down vote?